# PHP Symbol Filter Function For + and \

Tags: php

I have an PHP code that the function is to filter if variables contains some symbol.

The function :

```
function strposa($haystack, $needles=array(), $offset=0)
{
    $chr = array();
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
            $res = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
            if ($res !== false) $chr[$needle] = $res;
    }
    if(empty($chr)) return false;
    return min($chr);
}
```

Array :

```
$array  = array('*', '-', '/', '+', '.', '`', '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '(', ')', '_', '=', '|', ']', '[', '{', '}', ';', ':', '"', "'", '?', '>', '<', ',', ' ', '\');
```

Call the function :

```
if(strposa($accessories_sheet, $array, 1))
{}
```

My question is why for this symbol + and \ it cannot do the filter and always pass.

Need your advice.

Thank you

Comment: This will probably be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368313/php-check-if-special-characters-from-a-list-are-present-in-a-string/22371010#22371010

Comment: I dont know about the plus, but the '\' is an escape character, to search for it, use  \\ instead.cAlso you could have just used in_array instead of writing your own function. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php